# Javascript Regex multi-line base64

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following from a MIME message;

```
--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0NCg0KSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgdGV4dA0KDQpOb3cgb24gYSAzcmQg
bGluZQ0KDQoNClRoYW5rcw0KDQo=

--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF--
```

I want to extract the base64 encoded message, regardless of how many lines it is.

The following will indeed find matches on each individual line, but how can I group them so that if there are multiple lines of base64 that matches, it will group them as "together"

```
var base64Regex = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}={2})$/gm
```

When the MIME content for example also contains a PGP signature, this would give me 4 or 5 matches, so I can't simply join them, because it will find that base64 as well.

Ideally I'd modify this so it gets everything from/including the first match to `----------` and says that is "match 1" and if it finds another block of base64, that is "match 2", etc.

Here is a link to regex101 showing 2 matches. In short, I would like for this to be one match.

https://regex101.com/r/32WjKa/1

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
var base64Regex = /Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64([\s\S]*?)\s*?--/g;
```

`Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` - This is the start of the base64 encoded message.

`[\s\S]*?` - This is the base64 encoded message. It can be on multiple lines.

`\s*? --` - This is the end of the base64 encoded message.

`g` - This is the global flag, so that it will match all instances of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for base64 characters, I'd look for all characters (including newlines) between the start and end of the HTTP payload.

By default, `.` in Javascript regexes, even in mulit-line mode, won't match linebreaks. But the `/s` flag allows for `.` to match linebreaks.

With this method, you can remove linebreaks after you match with a simple `replace()`

```
const str = `--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0NCg0KSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgdGV4dA0KDQpOb3cgb24gYSAzcmQg
bGluZQ0KDQoNClRoYW5rcw0KDQo=

--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF--`

const payload = str.match(/base64\n\n(.+)\n\n--------------.+/ms)[1].replace(/\n/g, '')
```

You might also be better off using something like [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) since HTTP payloads like this are standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions, one using a regex `.replace()`, the other one using a `.match()` with positive lookbehind and positive lookahead:

```js
const input = `--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0NCg0KSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgdGV4dA0KDQpOb3cgb24gYSAzcmQg
bGluZQ0KDQoNClRoYW5rcw0KDQo=

--------------ra650umTsDNeI5lwXmFy5luF--`;

const regex1 = /^.*?Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s+(.*?)\s*---.*$/is;
let result1 = input.replace(regex1, '$1');
console.log(result1);

const regex2 = /(?<=Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s+).*?(?=\s*---)/is;
let result2 = input.match(regex2);
console.log(result2[0]);
```

Output:

```
TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0NCg0KSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgdGV4dA0KDQpOb3cgb24gYSAzcmQg
bGluZQ0KDQoNClRoYW5rcw0KDQo=

TG9yZW0gSXBzdW0NCg0KSGVyZSBpcyBzb21lIG1vcmUgdGV4dA0KDQpOb3cgb24gYSAzcmQg
bGluZQ0KDQoNClRoYW5rcw0KDQo=
```

Explanation of regex 1 for `.replace()`:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `.*?Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s+` -- literal text up to `base 64`, and including whitespace
- `(.*?)` -- capture group one: non greedy capture all, until:
- `\s*---.*` -- whitespace, `---`, and everything after that
- `$` -- anchor at end of string
- use `is` flags for case insensitive, and to match newlines with `.`, respectively

Explanation of regex 2 for `.match()`:

- `(?<=Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\s+)` -- positive lookbehind for literal text `...base64`, including whitespace
- `.*?` -- non-gridy scan, until:
- `(?=\s*---)` -- positive lookahead for whitespace and `---`
- use `is` flags for case insensitive, and to match newlines with `.`, respectively

**Notes:**

- Keep in mind that not all regex flavors and browsers support lookbehind, notably Safari
- It is safe to scan for `---` to find the end because dashes are not part of base64 characters